# WordPress Twenty Thirteen Theme: How to hide ".entry-content" only on main page

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to hide the body text below the headlines on my blog's main page, the page where all articels are listed, but would like keep it on the single post page.

My first thought was to set `.entry-content` to `display:none` but this made it disappear on both pages.

Does anyone have an idea how to remove it only on the front page?

Comment: It sounds like something that should be done programmatically by PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress assigns a unique class to the body for each page. you can see the body classes by viewing source. Home page is given the class `.home` so you could target entry-content this way:

```
.home .entry-content{ display:none; }
```

alternatively you can create a custom template for your home page and just remove the html.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates